# LINQ - search between IList and list of strings

Tags: c#, linq

Im not very well versed in LINQ and I think this problem could be solved with it.

I have a list of objects:

```
IList<Aclass> allADs;
```

Class:

```
public static class Aclass
{
    private string myName { get; set; }
    //And more attributes.
}
```

And I have a list of strings:

```
List<string> lstGroups = new List<string>();
```

At this point in my code both my list of objects and the list of strings are full. What I want is a list of `Aclass` that matches the property `myName` with the strings of the list. the list of strings have unique elements, there is no repetition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Contains`:

```
var res = lstAclass.Where(a => lstGroups.Contains(a.MyName)).ToList();
```

When `lstAclass` has lots of elements, you can speed up the search by constructing a `HashSet` of group names prior to running this query:

```
var setGroups = hew HashSet<string>(lstGroups);
var res = lstAclass.Where(a => setGroups.Contains(a.MyName)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, now, I have a variation but I dont know if I have to create a new post. May I ask you in the comment section and would you be able to answer it?

Comment: @user3442470 If your follow-up is sufficiently different, please post it as a separate question, and then post a link to it in a comment to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the [Enumerable.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx) method performs a case-sensitive equality comparison.

If you want to ignore case-sensitivity, then add `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`:

```
var matches = allADs.Where(a => lstGroups.Contains(a.myName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
```

Comment: This is VERY important, thank you for bringing this. +1
Did not know it performs case-sensitive comparison.