# Search with more criteria in Lambda Expression between two lists

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

This is a variation of my preview question, you can see this in this link:
[LINQ - search between IList and list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254263/linq-search-between-ilist-and-list-of-strings)

Now, as per the question before, I have two lists, one is a list of objects, the class is the following:

```
public class ProfileAD
{
    public string GroupAD { get; set; }
    public string Profile{ get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
}
```

The other list is of strings: `List<string> nameProfilesAD`

The list of `nameProfilesAD` is the name of the group of Active Directory where the user have, so the user could have 5 groups for example.

Now as you see, the list of Objects `ProfileAD` have two properties, one is the `GroupAD` (The name of the group) and `Priority`.

The idea is to make a Lambda expression where it saves the object that **matches** both the name between the attribute `GroupAD` of my Object and one of the elements of my list **and** is the highest priority.

One more thing, the list of objects is ordered by priority, so you will get the biggest priority first, and because we want the biggest priority, it needs to stop there, no need to keep searching for the biggest number/same name. Both lists could have different amount of elements.

Comment: What have you tried? What is your specific problem? Do you mean like a Where().OrderBy().First()?

Comment: If it is already sorted, you can simply use `FirstOrDefault()`. Otherwise please specify what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: bad question, You must to ask technical question not like this

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: Thanks Adwaenyth. Yep, it was really simple, did not see it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it wasn't so different from the other lambda expression really.

Here is the Lambda expression:

```
User.ProfileAD = nameProfilesAD.Where(a => nameProfilesAD.Contains(a.GroupAD)).FirstOrDefault();
```